# Is it possible to obtain elapsed time of playing media when it's called from the other website using iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

When it's showing video with HTML5's video tag, it can obtain elapsed time.
For that, I coded just like this.

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" name="media">
    <source src="test_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<button name="test" onclick="alert(Math.floor(document.getElementById('video').currentTime) + ' secs elapsed!');">
    How many seconds elapsed?
</button>

<button name="test" onclick="document.getElementById('video').currentTime = 120;">
    Start playing at 120 secs
</button>
```

What if I'm doing the same thing when if video is called from the other web site using iframe?
How can I code?

```
<iframe src="http://flashservice.xvideos.com/embedframe/3109336" frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no></iframe>
```

Comment: Only if that service provides an API of some kind like Vimeo and Youtube do.

Comment: @kalley Thanks for a comment. So in this case, it's impossible?